# force_ssl working for http://www.domain.com but not http://domain.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

http://www.domain.com forwards to https://www.domain.com
but http://domain.com doesn't forward to https://domain.com

I am using nginx and unicorn, is there a way to fix this issue just in rails?  Or does it require a nginx/unicorn settings change?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/stjhimy/rack-www to redirect all requests over to the www domain.

```
config.middleware.use Rack::WWW, :www => true
```